# How to show seekbar along with the custom mediaplayer

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player, seekbar

i have build a custom media player and i want to show the seekbar also.
The seekbar is showing for now but is not functional i.e. it is not progressing when the song is played. Let me know where am i wrong . Following is the code

```
public class myPlayer extends Activity implements Runnable,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    Button play,stop;
    SeekBar seekbar;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sajnave);
        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        Toast.makeText(myPlayer.this, ""+mPlayer.getDuration(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mPlayer.start();

            }

        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(myPlayer.this, ""+mPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mPlayer.stop();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int currentPosition = 0;

                int total = mPlayer.getDuration();

                seekbar.setMax(total);

                while (mPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        return;

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        return;

                    }

                    seekbar.setProgress(currentPosition);

                }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mPlayer.seekTo(arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `updatePosition()` method after mediplayer starts..It works for me.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updatePosition();
    }
};

private void updatePosition() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
    if (player != null) seekbar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());

    handler.postDelaye(updatePositionRunnable, 500);

}
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    player.seekTo(arg1);
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: I think that it would be better to modify onProgressChanged method a little bit:
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int prgress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser)
       player.seekTo(progress);
}

Without if condition, you will get feeling the sound keeping paused shortly and playing again while playing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SurfaceView mPreview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);    
mPreview.postDelayed(runnable,200);    
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            if (isPlaying) {
                // converting current position into seconds so dividing by
                // 1000
                try {
                    currentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    mVideoProgress
                            .setProgress((int) ((currentPosition / (float) mMediaPlayer
                                    .getDuration()) * 100f));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mPreview.postDelayed(runnable, 150);
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Mohit, you may put your first 3 lines into code view, that may be better and more readable.